# Moving From Owin Katana To IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

I have an app.Run() statement in Owin Katana. After it is finished running, I want to return to MVC, but not sure how.

```
app.Run(context =>
{
    if (!ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    context.Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {    RedirectUri = "http://domain.com" }, "Microsoft");
         context.Set<int>("owin.ResponseStatusCode", 401);
         return context.Response.WriteAsync("Redirecting...");
    }
    return Task.FromResult(context);
    });
}
```

The server doesn't respond to the next incoming request. Rather every authenticated request is blank. It's like it's stuck in the middleware, and doesn't see the MVC controller.

Comment: I would think this isn't the right way to do this.  It looks like you are redirecting if you aren't authenticated, before you are actually reaching the method which would perform the authentication.  Essentially you are stuck in an infinite loop here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is redirect to the authentication server if unauthenticated. Otherwise continue on to MVC. It is import that the redirect to the auth server occurs on first request so that the first thing the uses sees is the auth server's login page.

Comment: right, but how is the authentication server setting the `IsAuthenticated` property on this server?

Comment: Ah... I think I get it. The redirect request coming back from the Auth server is not authenticated at that time, so it's redirected back to the Auth server again. Thanks.

Comment: So, I don't want Is Request Authenticated? I want Does Request Have External Cookie?

Comment: How are your middlewares configured? The Auth server should be redirecting to "http://domain.com" after authentication and that time isAuthenticated should be set to true.